# how to reduce toast_tuple_threshold in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

OS: RHEL 7.2
PostgreSQL Version 9.6

I want toast to compress data. The average record length is around 500 Bytes in my tables. Although the columns show storage as extended, yet no compression is happening. Hence I want to modify toast_tuple_threshold to 500 bytes. Which file holds this value? And do we need to modify any other parameter?

Comment: I think you can only change that if you compile Postgres yourself.

Comment: can you please list out the dependent src files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE tablename SET (TOAST_TUPLE_TARGET = 128);
```

Comment: That's a different setting and it only comes into play when toasting is already triggered.